# Compare Two Matrices Containing NaN and Mask the Element Values in Both Matrices Where at Least One of Them Contains NaN in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have two 3D matrices (A and B), both containing NaN in random elements. I am comparing these two matrices and in places where at least one of them contains NaN I want both of them to contain NaN. In other words, if the both of them don't already contain NaN at that index, I want to replace that index value with NaN. Is there an efficient way to do this with a python function?

```
import numpy as np

# Create the fake variables A and B. Here is what A and B look like initially:
A = np.array([[1, 2, np.nan], [4, np.nan, 6], [np.nan, 8, 9]])
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, np.nan], [np.nan, 8, 9]])

# What I want A and B to look like in the end:
A
array([[  1.,   2.,  nan],
       [  4.,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,   8.,   9.]])

B
array([[  1.,   2.,   nan],
       [  4.,   nan,  nan],
       [ nan,   8.,   9.]])
```

Comment: Create your mask with `np.logical_or`. `np.logical_or(np.isnan(A), np.isnan(B))`

Comment: @ Kasramvd Thank you! This was also an elegant solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`numpy.isnan()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) and [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html).

```
>>> A[np.isnan(B)] = np.nan
>>> B[np.isnan(A)] = np.nan
```

Comment: Lovely! Thank you! I knew there had to be an easy function for this.